Clicking outside ng-select that is inside Swiper-js doesn't close the dropdown
I have an angular application v17 that is using swiper-js. In each swiper-slide I have a ng-select dropdown.
Had an issue where the dropdown didn't open, that was fixed by the latest answer on this post.
I can close the dropdown by selecting an option.
Right now the issue is that the dropdown doesn't close when clicking inside the .
        <ng-select
          class="swiper-no-swiping custom"
          [(ngModel)]="model"
          [searchable]="false"
          [clearable]="false"
          appendTo="body"
        >
          <ng-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.code">{{item.name}}</ng-option>
        </ng-select>

I already tried to change z-index in swiper-container. The ng-select is appended to body, since other places won't work.
